# Django - How to obtain corresponding row values from el-table after performing row-click?

Tags: python, html, django, database, element-ui

I created a table in Django where upon doing row-click, the records for the corresponding row should be POSTED to the function "***medicineRequestSelect***" in ***view_doctor.py***. However, it is unable to extract that row of values as shown in **Image 1**. It returns me None values.

I am relatively new to web development and any help or advice will be greatly appreciated!

**<doctor_emr.html>**

```
{% block mainbody%}

{% verbatim %}

<div id="app2" class="container">
  <div class="emr-table">
    <el-table
      ref="multipleTable"
      :data="list"
      stripe
      style="width: 50%"
      @row-click="handle"
      @selection-change="handleSelectionChange">
         
      <el-table-column
        prop="id"
        label="Index">
      </el-table-column>
      <el-table-column
        prop="order_id"
        label="Order ID">
      </el-table-column>
      <el-table-column
        prop="ward_number"
        label="Ward No.">
      </el-table-column>

      <el-table-column 
        prop="prop" 
        label="Scan QR" 
        width="width">

        <template slot-scope="{row$index}">
          <el-button @click="onScanQR(row)" type="warning" icon="el-icon-camera" size="mini">Scan</el-button>
        </template>

      </el-table-column>

    </el-table>
  </div>
</div>
{% endverbatim %}

<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app2',
        data() {
            return {
            list: []
        }
        },
        mounted() {
        this.getemrList()
        },
        methods: {
            getemrList() {
            // Obtain EMR list
            axios.post(ToDJ('emrList'), new URLSearchParams()).then(res => {
                if (res.data.code === 0) {
                    console.log(res.data.data)
                    this.list = res.data.data
                } else {
                    this.NotifyFail(res.data.data)
                }
            })
            },

            // Purpose: For the row click
            handle(row, event, column) {
              console.log(row, event, column)
              axios.post(ToDJ('medicineRequestSelect'), new URLSearchParams()).then(res => {
                if (res.data.code === 0) {
                  console.log(res.data.data)
                  this.list = res.data.data
                  let index = this.list.findIndex(item => {
                    return item.id == row.id
                  })
                  if (index == -1) {
                    this.$refs.multipleTable.toggleRowSelection(row, true);
                    this.list.push(row)
                  } else {
                    this.$refs.multipleTable.toggleRowSelection(row, false);
                    this.list.splice(index, 1)
                  }

                  } else {
                    this.NotifyFail(res.data.data)
                  }
                })  
              },
            
            onScanQR(row) {
              this.dialogFormVisible = true;
              this.tmForm={...row}
            },

            // Success notification
            NotifySuc(str) {
                this.$message({
                    message: str,
                    type: 'success'
                })
            },
            // Error notification
            NotifyFail(str) {
                this.$message({
                message: str,
                type: 'warning'
            })
            }
        }
    })
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

**<view_doctor.py>**

```
@api_view(['GET',"POST"])
def medicineRequestSelect(request):
  
  id = request.POST.get('id')
  order_id = request.POST.get('order_id')
  ward_number = request.POST.get('ward_number')
  print("Values: ", id, order_id, ward_number)
  
  return Action.success()
```

**Image 1: Output Obtained**

[image]

**Image 2: Table I created**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm also learning, and I try to progress by trying to help other's problem.

First where are you getting your data's from? From your Models?

So if I understood correctly you should import the model you want your data from  and then make queries to it using your model.

model = *TheNameOfYourModel*.objects.all()

and then you can make your queries using q

PS: I'm still learning, i'm curious to see the answer of someone experienced

Comment: My data is pre-loaded into postgresql and reflected on the webpage. The idea behind this, the table consist of a bunch of pre-loaded data and upon clicking it (serves as completed), that particular row is supposed to disappear.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).